# How to align Menu with Slideshow

Tags: html, css

I have a website im creating in notepad , and i cant seem to get the css menu to line up

exactly rite with my javascript slideshow

i can mess with the padding to make the menu longer but it still wont line up corerctly

here is a image of the webpage

http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/2/websitequestion1.jpg

and here is the code ,

```
  <head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="galleria/galleria-1.2.8.js"></script>
    <style>
        #galleria{ width: 1020px; height: 386px;margin:0px auto;}
           body
     {
      background-image:url('bg.jpg');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      } 
      body {

            text-align: center;
        }
     /* Menu Start Here */

       #menu li {
            display: inline;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #menu li a {

            border: 1px solid white;
            padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color:black;
            margin-left: -5px;
            /* This is the background used for the animation */
            background-image: url('image2.jpg');
            /* Align the image position to the left of the a */
            background-position: left;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
            /* Animation with transition in Firefox (No supported Yet) */
            -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
            /* Animation with transition in Opera (No supported Yet)*/
            -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
        }

        #menu li a:hover {
            color: white;
            /* Align the image position of the background to the right*/
            background-position:right;
        }

    </style>
    </head>
     <body>

         <div id="wrap">




        <h1> </h1>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Products</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Services</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">About</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>


    </div>
    <div id="galleria">
        <img src="pic1.jpg">
        <img src="pic2.jpg">
        <img src="pic3.jpg">
        <img src="pic4.jpg">


    </div>
    <script>
        Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
        Galleria.run("#galleria"); 

    </script>

     </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this:

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: 380px;
```

To the desire divs that you want to centered. In you case I would add a DIV arround the galeria just to centered it.

Comment: if i put margin 0 auto the menu splits up into different blocks for each link . i want it to stay the same(as the picture) with the menu staying as one block but stretching and aligning with the slideshow

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the default user agent stylesheets are causing the unordered list to be shifted as well.

```
#menu { margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; }
```

Might help with that, many browsers add left margin to list elements by default

Comment: thanks this lined it up in the center of the slideshow not i just need to find a better way to stretch it , instead of using padding

Comment: i would vote you up and declare this answered but i need more points or something . either way you got it right thanks buddy

Comment: No problem at all, glad to have helped, and wish I had some better direction on having the individual buttons grow to fill in the area better

Comment: i got it to work good with just padding . i then had to enlarge my mouse over image to fit the new size of the menu .. thanks again buddy

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want your #galleria and #wrap divs to have the same width and margin, so add:

```
#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1020px;
}
```

Next, for your menu items to be the right size, you'll need to ditch display:inline; for your list items (because you can't set a width on inline items. So you'll want something like:

```
#menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

#menu li a {
    display: block;
}
```

You could just as easily use display:inline-block; depending on the browsers you need to support. There are several ways to go about it, but this should get you going in the right direction. Also, if you're floating your li, you'll need to add overflow:hidden; or float:left; or use a clear fix method on the ul so that the floats are contained.

Comment: i tried it and everything goes out of whack , i loose the js slideshow and other troubles .